# How to loop through multiple models in Phalcon with.volt files

Tags: join, models, phalcon, has-many, volt

I have three models in my project and I need to loop through all these models to display the content of 3 tables. SO wat I wnat to know is how to display a has many to belongs to relation in .volt file(a join in sql)?

Comment: Please support us with example of what you already tried and what kind of data you want to loop through.

Comment: Please clarify your question and add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass to view variable with your model and then in view:

```
{% for item in model.alias of related relation %}
do something with item
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks dude I finally got it to work by using the alias in the models